# How do I change XCOM 2's graphics without loading the game?

Tags: xcom-2

XCOM 2 has defaulted to maximum graphics, which my PC cannot handle. Unfortunately, this includes the background of the main menu which now crashes whenever I try to load it.

Since I can't get to the game options, is there a config file outside the game that I can edit? Perhaps a way to boot the game in safe mode?

Comment: A clean config file with minimum settings would also do, but I can't ask for that in the question body.

Comment: Let me see if I can find the graphics config file; I've seen it before so I should be easy enough to sort for you.

Comment: If you deleted the config file and then did Steam's "verify files", would you not end up with a clean default one?

Comment: @SimonW Unfortunately not- it's defaulting to Maximum anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://segmentnext.com/2016/02/06/xcom-2-pc-tweaks-guide-baseengine-ini-file-tweaks-for-improved-performance/):

Edit `Steam\steamapps\common\XCOM 2\Engine\Config\BaseEngine.ini`, and disable settings as appropriate. For a really quick attempt at just being able to get in game, I'd recommend (though this probably won't be playable) -

- DetailMode=1
- DirectionalLightmaps=False
- Distortion=False
- DropParticleDistortion=False
- CompositeDynamicLights=False
- ScreenPercentage=50.00

That last one will cause the game to render at a lower resolution and upscale it - if you want to change the games resolution instead, try opening `\Steam\steamapps\common\XCOM 2\XComGame\Config\DefaultEngine.ini` and editing the following values:

- ResX=(add your preferred horizontal resolution here)
- ResY=(add your preferred vertical resolution here)

Comment: The linked page mentions CompositeDynamicLights, Distortion, and DropParticleDistortion as heavy offenders for older machines. They might be causing the crashing.